# How to deactivate linux page/disk cache?

Tags: storage, cache

I would like to turn off the disk / storage cache on Raspbian. I have done a serie of benchmarks on the microSD (http://jgp.net/microsd-card-performance-raspberry-pi/) but some people recommended I do the benchmarks with out cache activated.

As a more general question, is there a way to choose how much cache you want?

Comment: *"some people recommended I do the benchmarks with out cache activated."* -> Perhaps suggests an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) in that what you really want to do is **clear** the cache; see [`/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt).  In any case, this is really a question about the linux kernel and has been appropriately migrated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the `direct=true` parameter in `fio`.  See the man page `open(2)` on the equivalent creation flag:

> O_DIRECT.
>     Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this  file.
>     In  general  this  will degrade performance, but it is useful in
>     special situations, such  as  when  applications  do  their  own
>     caching.   File I/O is done directly to/from user-space buffers.

Comment: It appears that fio --direct is not documented anymore. It still works with --direct=0 or --direct=1, but does not seem to do much.

Comment: did you try adding the line `direct=1` after the `size=` lines in the *.fio files?

Comment: Sorry -- it is documented, but it does not seem to affect the results on the platform (Raspberry Pi).

Comment: Yes on `direct=1` - sorry - it does not seem to affect the results, I will have more (heavier) tests to see if it affects it.